# Bash append to file with wildcards

Tags: bash, file, append, wildcard

I want to append a string to a file that contains wildcards

```
echo 'test' >>  /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
```

I always get the error that the file or directory does not exists.
When I cd to that directory it works flawless.
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
for x in /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*.default
do
  echo 'test' >> "$x"/prefs.js
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the * with a backslash.

You have

```
echo 'test' >>  /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
```

But it should be

```
echo 'test' >>  /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/\*.default/prefs.js
```

Are you sure you want to be editing the prefs.js file?

> User pref. files In the profile directory are two user pref files:
>   prefs.js and user.js.  prefs.js is automatically generated by the
>   application and should not be edited manually, whereas user.js is an
>   optional file the user can create to override preferences initialized
>   by other preferences files.
>   [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the error keeps the same: 
bash: /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please show the output of "ls -la /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/"

Comment: total 20
drwx------ 4 user php 4096 2013-08-31 11:56 .
drwx------ 4 user php 4096 2013-08-31 11:56 ..
drwx------ 2 user php 4096 2013-08-31 11:56 Crash Reports
-rw-r--r-- 1 user php   94 2013-08-31 11:56 profiles.ini
drwx------ 7 user php 4096 2013-08-31 11:56 wtnyitd1.default